# Incomplete confusion matrix when plotting with matshow

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, confusion-matrix

I'm trying to plot this confusión matrix:

```
[[25940  2141    84    19     3     0     0     1   184     4]
 [ 3525  6357   322    41     5     1     3     0   242     2]
 [  410  1484  1021    80     5     6     0     0   282     0]
 [   98   285   189   334     9     9     5     1   140     0]
 [   26    64    55    50   112    15     4     1    75     0]
 [   11    45    20    24     5   118     8     0    79     0]
 [    1     8     8     5     0    10    62     1    55     0]
 [    2     0     0     0     0     0     2     0     6     0]
 [  510   524   103    55     5     7     7     1 65350     0]
 [   62    13     2     1     0     0     1     0    11    13]]
```

Therefore, 10x10. Those 10 labels are:

```
[ 5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 14 15]
```

I use the following code:

## Get the confusion matrix

```
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred, labels=labels)
print('Confusion Matrix of {} is:\n{}'.format(clf_name, cm))
print(labels)
plt.matshow(cm, interpolation='nearest')
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xticklabels([''] + labels.astype(str).tolist())
ax.set_yticklabels([''] + labels.astype(str).tolist())
plt.title('Confusion matrix of the {} classifier'.format(clf_name))
plt.colorbar(mat, extend='both')
plt.clim(0, 100)
```

And I only get a plot with labels from 5 to 9:

[image]

What's the problem here?

Relevant imports and configuration (I'm working with Jupyter, btw):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
%matplotlib inline
plt.style.use('seaborn')
mpl.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 8, 6
```

I tried downgrading to matplotlib 3.1.0, as I read that something went wrong on 3.1.1 about seaborn, but anyway the result is the same (and also if I change style to ggplot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matplotlib doesn't put a label at every tick (to prevent overlapping ticks in case they would be longer). You can force ticks at every column with `ax.set_xticks(range(10))`.

Here is some example code, with calls adapted to matplotlib's ["object oriented"](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/tutorials/introductory/lifecycle.html) interface. Also, some extra padding prevents the title not to bounce with the top tick labels. Note that the labels can be numerically, matplotlib automatically interprets them as the corresponding strings. `ax.tick_params()`can help to remove the tick marks at bottom and top (or, alternatively, also get them left and/or right). The sample code also uses a grid on the minor xticks to make separations.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator
import numpy as np

cm = np.random.randint(0, 25000, (10, 10)) * np.random.randint(0, 2, (10, 10))
labels = np.array([5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
mat = ax.matshow(cm, interpolation='nearest')
mat.set_clim(0, 100)
ax.set_xticks(range(10))
ax.set_yticks(range(10))
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
ax.set_yticklabels(labels)
ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='both', bottom=False, top=False)

ax.grid(b=False, which='major', axis='both')
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(0.5))
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(0.5))
ax.grid(b=True, which='minor', axis='both', lw=2, color='white')

ax.set_title('Confusion matrix of the {} classifier'.format('clf_name'), pad=20)
plt.colorbar(mat, extend='both')
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]